# ReactJS changelistener for Flux not working

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am stuck on a issue involving adding a listener for Flux store properties. I am bouncing around the web for guidance and this has now been a circle that does not end.

My changeListener is not working and I am not sure why.

My code is as follows:

**AppStore**

```
imports...

const name = 'CHANGE';

class AppStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        
        this.data = {
            isLoading: { flag: false, content: '' }
        }
        
        dispatcher.register(this.registerToActions.bind(this));
    }
    
    registerToActions(action) {
        switch (action.actionType) {
            case STORE_CONST.loader:
                this.setLoader(action.payload);
                break;
                ...
        }
        // persist changes into store
        this.emit(name);
    }
    ...

    setLoader(data) {
        let loader = this.data.isLoading;
        loader.flag = data.flag;
        loader.content = data.content;
    }

    addChangeListener(callback) {
        this.on(name, callback);
    }

    removeChangeListener(callback) {
        this.removeListener(name, callback);
    }

    getAll() {
        return this.data;
    }
}

const appStore = new AppStore();

export default appStore;
```

**Store Usage**

```
import...

const initialState = {
    globalStore: appStore.getAll()
};

export class Omega extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = initialState;
        ...
    }

    onChange() {
        this.setState({globalStore: appStore.getAll()});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        appStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        appStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Any advise what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue, though I am not sure why it was not working and is now working.

In **AppStore**, the code below:

```
registerToActions(action) {
    switch (action.actionType) {
        case STORE_CONST.loader:
            this.setLoader(action.payload);
            break;
            ...
    }
    // persist changes into store
    this.emit(name);
}
```

I simply moved ***this.emit(name)*** out and added it directly to ***setLoader*** function, as shown below:

```
setLoader(data) {
    ...
    ...
    this.emit(name);
}
```

**Like I said, I do not know why it works after this fix.**